# How do I use the generic type T with Retrofit?

Tags: android, generics, retrofit

I want to use T in Retrofit, but I do not know, how to set T in Retrofit.create(X.class) method.

```java
public interface SupportService<T> {
    @GET
    Flowable<BaseResponse<T>> getApi(@Url String url, @Query("data") JsonObject jsonObject);
}
```

```
HttpRetrofit.getInstance()
                .getRetrofit(this)
                .<SupportService<T>>create(SupportService.class)
                .getApi("",null)
```

```
public class BaseResponse<T>{
    public int code;
    public String message;
    public T data;   
}
```

Comment: It get an error in this line..   <SupportService<T>>create(SupportService.class)

Comment: what are you want to do ?. Might just have a look on this. It might help you. https://github.com/sushildlh/Modules/wiki/Retrofit

Comment: I know how to use retrofit. but I just wanna to use T in Api interface. like public interface SupportService<T> {}. it seems that the T will get error when retrofit to create(ApiInterface.class). Just like the code above.

Comment: yeah it will give you error. Bcoz square doesn't predict your situation.

Answer (score 0):

"T" stays for a generic type of your choice. In retrofit, you can define your data model class accordingly to api response, for example with `@SerializedName` annotation if you are using GSON as serializing library. That "T" type will be the class defined for the api response. [Here](https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial) you can find a simple starting point tutorial about retrofit.

Comment: Is it mean I should not use T in the api interface?   If I want to use , what should I do? for example in your APIInterface class, how do I add a T to it?

Comment: You have to specify a type, if your response is in JSON format you can specify Object as the most generic type possible

Comment: at last, I choose to use jsonObject instead

Comment: If you can post the response of your api I can help you

Comment: Hi,  Nicola Gallazzi. I have posted my response, could you have a try?